# The page you were looking for doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to learn Rails ( developpment beginner here )

When I try to deploy my first app on Heroku and execute `$ heroku open` I got 
"The page you were looking for doesn't exist.”

In my Heroku control pannel I also have a second link who works, http://secret-refuge-2130.herokuapp.com/, but different from localhost.

Here's my first app https://github.com/Freysh/first_app

Comment: Does `heroku open` give you any other information, such as what URL it's attempting to use?

Comment: @jdl Heroku try to open testkeryh.herokuapp.com
( I changed the link via the console to test )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Hartl propose 
"Unfortunately, the resulting page is an error; as of Rails 4.0, for technical reasons the default Rails page doesn’t work on Heroku. The good news is that the error will go away (in the context of the full sample application) when we add a root route in Section 5.3.2."
You need to work on the Root route of your routes.rb in config folder.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't pushed your repo to `Heroku` yet?

Since you're new, let me give you some ideas about how Heroku works, and how you can deploy your app to it...

---

**Heroku**

When you use Heroku, you basically [get a `bare` git repo](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server) which you can push your application to. This repo will essentially allow you to use the following commands:

```
> $ git add .
> $ git commit -a -m "Your App"
> $ git push heroku master
```

This is, of course, only possible if you have added your [`heroku` repo](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) to your local `remote` repositories:

```
> $ git remote add heroku https://heroku.com/......
```

When you push your local repo to your Heroku one, Heroku then runs what's known as a [`buildpack`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks):

> When you git push heroku, Heroku’s slug compiler prepares your code
>   for execution by the Heroku dyno manager. At the heart of the slug
>   compiler is a collection of scripts called a buildpack.
>   Heroku’s Cedar
>   stack has no native language or framework support; Ruby, Python, Java,
>   Clojure, Node.js and Scala are all implemented as buildpacks.

This means that when you push your app to your repo, Heroku will endeavour to compile & run it for you. This is when the app will run.

---

**Fix**

To fix, you should [follow the tutorial here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

Basically, you need to get your `git` repo created locally, which will then provide you with the ability to push to your remote `heroku` repo

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I followed your instructions, when i use `git remote-v` I see `heroku git@heroku.com:tranquil-mountain-2647.git` so the heroku repo is add to my local remote repositories.

But when I use `heroku open` I got this : [link](http://tranquil-mountain-2647.herokuapp.com) ..

Comment: This is VERY good! It means your Rails app is on Heroku - you just have a snytax issue. Type `heroku logs` in your console to see what's the problem. If you post the repsonse, I'll be in a better position to help!

Comment: @Rick Peck 
I can't paste the whole code here, it's too big. What do you need precisely ? Or how can I paste it ? Thanks

Comment: Can you post in pastebin.com?

Comment: @Rick Peck
You can find the code here, thanks [link](http://pastebin.com/yN7QP9vJ)